# Swap hardrives of window and ubuntu systems

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, windows-10

I have two laptops.

`Lenovo T430S (Installed Ubuntu 16.04)` and `HP EliteBook (Installed Windows 10)` with same specs.

Both are

1. Core I5
2. 8 GB RAM
3. 256 SSD

I want to swap their Hard-drives so that I can have my `Ubuntu on HP Elitebook` and `Windows on Lenovo`.

My question here is.

Would it corrupt my Ubuntu PC ? I don't care about windows. We can reinstall it. But I don't want to hurt my Ubuntu PC Data.